# Unit Testing in Commerce tools in .net/C# API

Tags: commercetools

What unit testing framework/library is recommended for Commerce tools in.net/C# API especially for mocking the commerce tool .net API .

I tried mocking the .net API of commerce tools with moq framework but faced issues in that . It does not let mock the objects saying overriding is not allowed .